# Android Studio 2.2: Android studio 2.2 stable release missing Preview all screen sizes feature

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, graphical-layout-editor, layout-editor

I download and update my android studio to 2.2 stable version and now i found that it missing the feature of preview all screen sizes. so now how to preview 
all screen sizes in android studio 2.2? is it possible through android studio 2.2?

Comment: Good, thanks to review us the new "Android Studio 2.2" but... what's your code question?

Comment: you can resize the preview screen to see how your layout would look on different screen sizes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct. [According to Google](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/ou0gRsrSkEg/NFn2VoeACQAJ), "we plan to restore it (in a better way) in an upcoming version".